# Seeing file names in SCP

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, scp

I'm using `scp` to copy files from a remote server to a local one. What's really uncomfortable is that I need to type the file path precisely. I'm used to relying on autocompletion, because file names and folder structures can be long. I want to be able to see the names of files in each directory and autocomplete just like when browsing files locally.

Now, I could do SSH separately, find the file names, and use them in the SCP command. But of course, that would be a huge waste of effort. Also, I could use a GUI, but I prefer to avoid that because a command line is more lightweight.

**Any way to use SCP without having to remember file names exactly?**

Comment: For me, auto completion works if I have set key-based password less login.

Comment: There's also the problem with special characters (though they shouldn't be used). With files containing such characters, `zsh` seems OK, but `bash-completion` isn't (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bash-completion`](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) (which is available in Cygwin, Debian, Ubuntu and no doubt many other distributions) supports `scp` auto-completion, as long as the shell can access the required server with no prompting (it uses `ssh` in batch mode, see the [`ssh_config(5)` manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5) for details).

The easiest way to enable this is to use `ssh-agent`. This is probably enabled by default by your desktop environment; simply try

```
ssh-add
```

to add your default key to the currently-running agent (if any). If no agent is running, you can start one by running

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Once your key is known to the agent, you'll be able to auto-complete `scp` commands involving servers you can access with the key.

I'm pretty sure `zsh` also supports `scp` auto-completion with the same caveats; the necessary support is in the `zsh-common` package in Debian. It needs to be enabled in your `.zshrc` though with something like

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

(which loads all the supported completions).

Answer (score 1):

Zsh has remote `scp` completion, but you need to make sure that you don't use an alias to some wrapper function like the non-official [`glob_scp`](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2004/msg00753.html), or if you have one, it is possible to add the same completion mechanism like:

```
compdef glob_scp=scp
```

You'll note that `zsh` will correctly quote special characters such as `*` when needed (though this may look strange). Currently `bash-completion` [doesn't do that](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=778339), though failures should be uncommon.

Alternatively, in particular with shells that do not have remote `scp` completion, you could use `sftp` or `sshfs`:

- `sftp` has its own completion system.
- `sshfs` allows you to mount a remote directory via SSH, so that it suffices to use `cp` with the usual completion system.

Comment: @muru Thanks, but this wasn't the reason (I use password-less SSH). The reason was that I was using an alias to the non-official `glob_scp` function (unfortunately the message in the mailing-list didn't mention the effect on the completion). I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Interesting. +1 and deleting my comment.